# How to update a datetime field with timezone in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

As the question states i tried

```
UPDATE mytable set end_date="2015-07-17 22:00:00+00" WHERE id=8244;
```

But this does not work for obvious reasons, all the detail on the web is about searching for dates not updating them, especially when they have timezones

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Postgres is a little different in that single and double quotes do *wildly* different things.

- Double quotes are used to denote [identifiers or keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)
- Single quotes denote [regular strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

So the fix here is to make sure to use single quotes:

```
UPDATE mytable set end_date='2015-07-17 22:00:00+00' WHERE id=8244;
```

Comment: oh so the double quotes were the problem

Comment: Yes. Double quotes are usually used to specify the delimited identifiers in the database. This is how they are defined in most of RDBMS.